# measure of the angle from a line with given slope

Tags: geometry

Can any one help me out in this question.
How to find the measure of the angle from a line with slope -2/3 to (i) y-axis (ii) x-axis?

Comment: If the line is given by $y = -\frac{2}{3}$, pick any point $(x,y)$ lying on the line (other than the origin) and then I believe that the angle with the $y$-axis will be $\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})$. What about the $x$-axis ?

Comment: along y-axis angle will be 90 and x-axis 0 degree.. I am just wondering around how to find out the angle using this formula.

Comment: Of course I meant $y = -\frac{2}{3} x$ in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

If your line is $y=ax+b$, i.e. has slope $a$, then the angle $\phi_x$ it makes with the $x$ axis is defined by $\tan\phi_x=a$ and the angle with the $y$ axis defined by $\cot\phi_y=a$.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Slope_definitions.

Comment: Thank you all... I want to know.. In book the angle along x-axis is arctan(2/3)where as given slope is -2/3. where the -ve sign?

Comment: @zonnie: Depends on whether you want a oriented (i.e. signed) angle, or only care about the absolute value of the angle. In the latter case, you can take the absolute value of the argument, which might be what this book is doing.

Comment: but along y-axis there is -ve signed angle i.e arctan(-1.5).. If we are taking absolute values then why not with y-axis?